# Excluding a src file from sbt compile?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been trying to exclude a file from "sbt run" and "sbt compile". The file is called SheetsQuickstart.java, and is in src/main/java. I'm using intelliJ's sbt shell to run these commands. (Perhaps it's not reading the build.sbt file?)

In build.sbt, I've tried lines like:

```
excludeFilter in (Compile, managedSources) := "SheetsQuickstart.java"
excludeFilter in managedSources := "SheetsQuickstart.java"
excludeFilter in unmanagedSources := "SheetsQuickstart.java"
excludeFilter in managedSources := "SheetsQuickstart.class"
excludeFilter in managedSources := "*.java" `
```

I still get compilation errors in SheetsQuickstart.java when I compile using sbt, despite having tried to exclude it.

Comment: `excludeFilter in unmanagedSources := "SheetsQuickstart.java"` should work. Do you have the same issue if your execute `sbt compile` from outside IntelliJ?

Comment: yes, i still do, it's still trying to compile SheetsQuickstart.java . the file is a file that I wrote in src/main/java but isn't compiling, is this the intended use of excludeFilter in unmanagedSources?

Comment: If you execute `show unmanagedSources` do you see `SheetsQuickstart.java` in the output?

Comment: Do you have any subprojects in the build? If this source is in a subproject, you need to scope the key by project, e.g. `projectFoo/unmanagedSources/excludeFilter := "SheetsQuickstart.java"`

Comment: @MarioGalic, yes, it does show SheetsQuickstart.java

Answer (score 0):

Add following to `build.sbt` to exclude file SheetsQuickstart.java from  compile:

```
unmanagedSources / excludeFilter := HiddenFileFilter || "SheetsQuickstart.java"
```